# call string value to URL in java

Tags: java, string, url, key-value

i have develop one android application.

here i have to pass string value to url.please tell me how can i pass the string  value to url.give me solution for these.

```
 String mTitle;

           String URL = "http://api1.sfsfsfffsf.com/dev/categories/?fields=&categoryid="+mTitle+"&access_token=bfb787a6e1";
          static String KEY_CATEGORY = "category";
// public static final String URL_Address=null;
        static final String KEY_TITLE = "categoryName";
        static final String KEY_NAME ="categoryId";
          static final String KEY_SUBCATE = "categoryId";
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.subcate);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
 mTitle = b.getString(KEY_SUBCATE);
 TextView grandtotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subcate);
   grandtotal.setText("Welcome ," + mTitle );
```

This is my url:
[http://api1.sfsfsfsff.com/dev/categories/?fields=&categoryid=10&access_token=bfb787a6e1112][1]

I have mentioned directly **categoryid=10** means have disaplyed all product.

But I have to change this url like:
[http://api1.sfsfsfsfsf.com/dev/categories/?fields=&categoryid="+mTitle+"&access_token=bfb787a6e1112][2]

Nw i have changed my url like **categoryid="+mTitle+"** means not displayed all products.

mTitle value is getting from my pervious activity.

whats wrong in my code.

**EDIT**:

my mTitle value is 10.i have to wrote the code like means

**grandtotal.setText("Welcome ," + mTitle );**

its displayed mTitle value successfully.

**grandtotal.setText("Welcome ," + URL );**

means gave me null value

Comment: just check what is your mTitle value

Comment: my mTitle value is 10.i have to wrote the code like means  grandtotal.setText("Welcome ," + mTitle ); its displayed mTitle value successfully.grandtotal.setText("Welcome ," + URL ); means gave me null value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
String mTitle;

           String URL = "http://api1.sfsfsffsf.com/dev/categories/?fields=&categoryid=" + mTitle + "&access_token=bfb787a";
          static String KEY_CATEGORY = "category";
// public static final String URL_Address=null;
        static final String KEY_TITLE = "categoryName";
        static final String KEY_NAME ="categoryId";
          static final String KEY_SUBCATE = "categoryId";
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.subcate);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
 mTitle = b.getString(KEY_SUBCATE);
 TextView grandtotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subcate);
   grandtotal.setText("Welcome ," + mTitle );
```

Error:

```
 String URL = "http://api1.sfsfsffsf.com/dev/categories/?fields=&categoryid=" + mTitle + "&access_token=bfb787a";
```

Correct Code:

```
String mTitle;

               String URL;
              static String KEY_CATEGORY = "category";
    // public static final String URL_Address=null;
            static final String KEY_TITLE = "categoryName";
            static final String KEY_NAME ="categoryId";
              static final String KEY_SUBCATE = "categoryId";
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.subcate);
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
     mTitle = b.getString(KEY_SUBCATE);

     URL = "http://api1.sfsfsffsf.com/dev/categories/?fields=&categoryid=" + mTitle +       "&access_token=bfb787a";
 TextView grandtotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subcate);
   grandtotal.setText("Welcome ," + mTitle );
```

Your mTitle is getting Initialized afterwards so you need to initialize URL after that only.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your Url as a string :-

```
String mTitle;
mTitle = b.getString(KEY_SUBCATE);
TextView grandtotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subcate);  
String url="http://api1.sfsfsffsf.com/dev/categories/?   fields=&categoryid="+mTitle+"&access_token=";
grandtotal.setText(url);
```

Comment: my mTitle value is 10.i have to wrote the code like means grandtotal.setText("Welcome ," + mTitle ); its displayed mTitle value is 10 successfully.grandtotal.setText("Welcome ," + URL ); means gave me null value